# Idiomatic migration of css class which was used on multiple elements to styled-components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

Given an existing class `form-control` which is being applied to various form tags e.g. `input` `select` `textarea` what is the idiomatic migration?

I'm guessing:

```
const formControlCss = `shared: css;`

const Input = styled.input`${formControlCss} \n more: css; `

const TextArea = styled.textArea`${formControlCss} \n more: css;`

const Select = styled.select`${formControlCss} \n more: css;`
```

This approach would probably lead me to having e.g. a `css.js` file that exports re-usable css snippets... which ironically seems like where I started - a file with lot's of styles in it!

Or

```
const FormControl = styled.div`font-size: and-other-css;` 

const Input = FormControl.withComponent('input').extend``

const TextArea = FormControl.withComponent('textarea').extend``

const Select = FormControl.withComponent('select').extend``
```

This approach to me seems to just be creating a superfluous base class with an irrelevant element... probably not good.

Or

```
const e = React.createElement

const FormControl = styled(({ tag, children, ...props }) => e(tag, props, children))`

<FormControl tag="input" />

<FormControl tag="textarea" />

<FormControl tag="select" />
```

Useful if there is no/little custom css on the different target elements, but it loses whitelisting.

Or

Any other options I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Two other ideas. One, you can create shared CSS snippets with the `css` template literal:

```
import {css} from 'styled-components'

const shared = css`
  // shared CSS
`

const TextArea = styled.textarea`
  ${shared}
`
```

These are kinda similar to mixins, if you're familiar with those from sass.

And two, you might be able to utilize the "cascading" part of CSS to eliminate the need to spread certain rules out to disparate components by moving whatever can be moved to a parent element up.